# match and copy

Tags: excel, lookup, worksheet-function, vba

Hi I am having some difficulty creating a macro - i need a macro whereby when the user input a dept code, the macro will take the number, go to first worksheet, read column B until it match the dept code, then copy all the appropriate rows for the dept code. I then need this to loop until the last worksheet. The workbook has about 9 worksheets.

Comment: You could use ADO to accomplish this - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819 for details

Answer (score 0):

does it really need to be VBA?

you could actually do this with the [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052093351033.aspx)-function.

you may pass your search criteria `'c'`, a table `'T'` and a column index `'i'`.
it will return you the content of the column `'i'` in `'T'` where column 1 matches your criteria `'c'`.

or am i misunderstanding your question?

regards

Answer (score 0):

tried that - basically, once the dept codes are matched, i am not returning a value, but an array range. For example, value in input in A1 (Sheet 1), then use the input to match all the values column A (A1:A99)in Sheet2. If there's a match, copy the heading rows and all other rows (A:ZZ)associated to the input value in an array format.